# AVD not available eclipse

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

I used eclipse to make a simple temperature conversion android application, but I have a problem with the android virtual device/emulator every time i run the app it says that no AVD available and no compatible targets were found. any help, please??

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the device in DDMS view in Eclipse.

Try the following command to start and stop adb server

> adb kill-server

and then

> adb start-server